# Using Celery from PHP?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm building a queue-based system to scale user-uploaded images.

Users will upload images which will get transferred to a storage server. The web server will then add a message to a queue which will be listened to by image scaling workers that will retrieve the image files, scale them and add them to the storage server.

I was planning on using celery over rabbitmq for this, but my web tier will be running PHP so for convenience I'd rather find a PHP way of doing this.

What suggestions do people have?

If it came to it (although I don't want to complicate the web tier by having python and PHP) how easy would it be to control celery from PHP, and how would I do that? Some kind of RPC protocol (like thrift?) or something simpler since celery needn't be on a different server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just use thrift to allow me to invoke python from php, and use python with celery.

Answer (score 7):

I made the [Celery-PHP](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php) library and it works smoothly for a few months now.

Answer (score 0):

Since https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php is now unmaintained and also missing some basic features (like forgetting a result or revoking/terminating a Celery task), I went ahead and created a modern `celery-for-php` library.

https://github.com/smuuf/celery-for-php

It currently supports using Redis as a result backend and a broker, and also AMQP/RabbitMQ as a broker.